# How to dismiss OAuth view?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, oauth

I have an app that logs into a 3rd party API via Oauth but I need some help removing my authorize view after successfully getting the token. Here's what I've got for the IB:
[image]

The app starts up with the regular ViewController and if there's no authToken presents the AuthView:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (myVars.authToken == "" ) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let authVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AuthViewController") as! AuthViewController
        self.navigationController?.showViewController(authVC, sender: self)
    }
```

You tap authorize, it opens the URL in Safari, you authorize the app, it returns the callback URL with the token which returns to the app with the authVC showing. But I can't seem to get my authVC to hide.

Any advice would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a new instance for the ViewController so I couldn't unwind it,etc. In the AppDelegate I got my existing nav controller & view

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let authView = navigationController.visibleViewController
```

Then I can call a function on the proper instance of authView that, among other things, unwinds the segue and gets me back to my usual nav flow.

There's probably a better solution but this is working.